# How to remove the duplicate lines retaining first occurences

Tags: python-2.7

Let's say a input text file "input_msg.txt" file contains follwing records..

Jan 1 02:32:40 hello welcome to python world
Jan 1 02:32:40 hello welcome to python world
Mar 31 23:31:55 learn python
Mar 31 23:31:55 learn python be smart
Mar 31 23:31:56 python is good scripting language
Jan 1 00:00:01 hello welcome to python world
Jan 1 00:00:02 hello welcome to python world
Mar 31 23:31:55 learn python
Mar 31 23:31:56 python is good scripting language

The expected output file ( Let's say  outputfile.txt ) should contain below records...

Jan 1 02:32:40 hello welcome to python world
Jan 1 02:32:40 hello welcome to python world
Mar 31 23:31:55 learn python
Mar 31 23:31:55 learn python be smart
Mar 31 23:31:56 python is good scripting language
Jan 1 00:00:01 hello welcome to python world
Jan 1 00:00:02 hello welcome to python world

Note: I need all the records (including duplicate) which are starting with "Jan 1(*)" and also I don't need Duplicate records not starting with "Jan 1(*)"

I have tried the following program where all the duplicate records are getting deleted.

```
def remove_Duplicate_Lines(inputfile, outputfile):  
   with open(inputfile) as fin, open(outputfile, 'w') as out:
      lines = (line.rstrip() for line in fin)
      unique_lines = OrderedDict.fromkeys( (line for line in lines if line) )
      out.writelines("\n".join(unique_lines.iterkeys()))
 return 0
```

Oputput of my program are below:

Jan 1 02:32:40 hello welcome to python world
Mar 31 23:31:55 learn python
Mar 31 23:31:55 learn python be smart
Mar 31 23:31:56 python is good scripting language
Jan 1 00:00:01 hello welcome to python world

Your help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
inputFile = open("in.txt", "r")
log = []
for line in inputFile:
    if line in log and line[0:5] != "Jan 1":
        pass
    else:
        log.append(line)
inputFile.close()

outFile = open("out.txt", "w")

for item in log:
    outFile.write(item)
outFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you!! if the input file size is 70GB will it be a performance issue??

Comment: @HelloR As long as you aren't reading the whole file into memory with readlines() or anything, I wouldn't think so. Iterating through each line will cause the previous line to be discarded.

Comment: I did just run this program with input file as 62728 KB, and it took ~8 minutes to completely the whole process. Can we do some elegant way here??

Comment: 8 minutes seems way too long. I just tested it on a ~113 MB file, and it took seconds.

Comment: @ Jeremy Anantharaj: Can we change something in my above code so that it will ignore all the "Jan  1" records...for your information OrderedDict.fromkeys() is the best way to do as far as performance is concerned...your code is working fine is lesser file size...